# Unit-tests for objective-c code with @avaliable attribute

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing

I have source code like this:

```
- (void)someMethod {

    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        [self doSomething];
    } else {
        [self doSomethingElse];
    }
}
```

Is it possible to cover somehow all code of this method by unit-tests? I mean is it possible to get to both sections 'if' and 'else' by unit-tests?

Comment: May be extract the sub flows into separate methods and test them individually?

Comment: Yes, probably it's only one variant.